# context and this android

Tags: android, this, android-context

I'm confuse with the 'context' and 'this', I'm not sure why the example below does not work.

I try to call the following sub class from my LoginActivity:

```
new SyncData(LoginActivity.this).execute(); // This will failed

public class SyncData  extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String> {
    private Context context;
    public SyncData(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    } 
    ProgressDialog progress=ProgressDialog.show( context, "", "Please wait...", true); //NOT WORK!!!
}
```

but if let say I change to this line it works:

```
ProgressDialog progress=ProgressDialog.show( LoginActivity.this, "", "Please wait...", true); // This will work
```

Can someone please explain to me how could i resolve this if i want to put the subclass in a new class file?

Comment: What do You mean by 'not work'? Do You get any exception or dialogue is no shown?

Comment: I've tested both variants on test app and both works just the same. Could You share more code / details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AsyncTask class, you declare `progress` progress to be a global variable, as you have put it outside a method block. Therefore, the line:

```
ProgressDialog progress=ProgressDialog.show( context, "", "Please wait...", true);
```

is executed when an object of `SyncData` is first made, and before your constructor is called. As your constructor hasn't been called yet, `context` is `null`, which results in an error when you try to use it.

Using `LoginActivity.this` instead of `context` works because `SyncData` is an inner class of `LoginActivity`, and you can thus access its scope from inside the inner class.

If you want to use `context`, try moving the assignment part of the `progress` declaration into a method that comes after the constructor, like `onPreExecute()`. Something like:

```
public class SyncData  extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String> {
    private Context context;
    ProgressDialog progress;
    public SyncData(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    } 

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress=ProgressDialog.show( context, "", "Please wait...", true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the `context` parameter of `SyncData` class is not initialized at time when you are trying to show ProgressDialog. Object parameters are initialized earlier than `SyncData` constructor is called.